# With directive comparing two inputs to make sure one is lower than the other, how can I trigger calculations on change of either input?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I have a directive called kcInputComparer which has a validator called lessThan.  I put this on one input which compares it to a second input.  If I change the value of the input with the validator, the validator fires and calculates, but if I change the second input, the validation doesn't happen.  Can I put some sort of $watch on the second input so the validation happens from the perspective of either?  Below is my directive:

```
angular.module('eFile.shared')
   .directive('kcInputComparer', function() {
     return {
       restrict: "A",
       require: "ngModel",
       link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
         ngModel.$validators.lessThan = function(modelValue) {
           if (modelValue && scope.lessThan) {
             return parseFloat(modelValue) < parseFloat(scope.lessThan);
           }
           return true;
         };
       },
       scope: {
         lessThan: '=lessThan'
       }
    };
});
```

So if I have:

```
<input id="input1" ng-model="vm.input1" kc-input-comparer less-than="vm.input2"/>
<input id="input1" ng-model="vm.input2"/>
```

And I put in 50 for input1 and 49 for input2, it'll be invalid.  If I set input1 to 48, it'll go back to being valid.  However, if I have 50 for input1 and 49 for input2 and I change input2 to 51, nothing happens.  I need to be able to trigger that.

Comment: Yes you can put a $watch within your directive to trigger the validation.

Comment: What would that look like?  Can I just put $watch(scope.lessThan?)

Comment: @sheilak just answered how you could do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validator will only automatically trigger when the model value is changed.

You can use `$watch` along with `ngModel.$validate()` to trigger validation like this:

```
scope.$watch(function () {
    return scope.lessThan;
  }, function () {
    ngModel.$validate();
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/ebr2a664/)